# Pythonnet ModuleNotFoundError with third-party PORTABLE library

Tags: c#, python, .net, python.net

I'm trying to use the Arendi BLE library on Python with Pythonnet, but I'm always getting a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Arendi'` error. Here's the code:

```
import sys

sys.path.append(r"C:\project\MyProj\references")

import clr

import System
import System.Collections
import System.Diagnostics
import System.Linq
import System.Reflection
import System.Runtime
import System.Text
import System.Text.RegularExpressions
import System.Threading
import System.Threading.Tasks

clr.AddReference(r"Arendi.DotNETLibrary")
clr.AddReference(r"Arendi.DotNETLibrary.Windows")
clr.AddReference(r"log4net")
clr.AddReference(r"Newtonsoft.Json")
clr.AddReference(r"Arendi.BleLibrary")

from Arendi.BleLibrary import Constants
```

The C:\project\MyProj\references dir has the Arendi.BleLibrary.dll plus all the dependencies (Arendi.DotNetLibrary, Arendi.DotNetLibrary.Windows, log4net, Newtonsoft.Json).

This particular library is a portable library and the targets are .NET Framework 4.5, ASP.NET Core 1.0, Windows 8, Windows Phone 8.1, Windows Phone Silverlight 8

I've looked here for a solution, but didn't find any:

- [pythonnet - Python for .NET](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet)
- [Troubleshooting on Windows, Linux, and OSX](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Troubleshooting-on-Windows,-Linux,-and-OSX)

I also used [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) to check the dependencies, but they all seem to be met.

Does anyone have an idea on how to debug this? Is there any particular compilation option for the library I should use?

Environment:

- Python 3.6.6 64 bits
- Python 3.6.6 32 bits
- pythonnet-2.3.0
- .NET Framework 4.5.2

Edit:
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442764/how-to-load-portable-net-library-within-iron-python-script/18004776) is related and trying IronPython seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: ever got this working?

Comment: No, I just gave up and used IronPython.